# How to specify type in docstrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, docstring

I use PyCharm to write my Python 3.6 scripts and just discovered the power of docstrings. I would like to know more about **type**.

What if I use a **pandas data frame** as my argument or what if I use an argument of **pywin32-object**, that I got from Outlook?

If I want to fill the type of an argument, do I have to type the complete class name?
For now I do `type(dataframe)` to get the class name. I copy that information to my docstring: `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` would be 
`pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` in my docstrings.

**Result:**

```
def my_fun(dataframe, mail_object):
    """
    Some informative text
    Parameters
    ----------
    dataframe : pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
        This is my dataframe to start with
    mail_object : win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6._MailItem
        My mail object of Outlook
    Returns
    -------
    arguments_dict : dict

    """
```

So is it correct to write **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame** as type for argument **dataframe** and **win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6._MailItem** as type for mail_object?
Moreover, what happens if the text of win32.com is dynamic? This time it is `win32com.gen_py.00062FFF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x9x6._MailItem`, but next time it is `win32com.gen_py.01245._MailItem`

Comment: Python3 supports type hints: `def my_func(dataframe: pandas.core.frameDataFrame, ...) -> dict`. Regarding dynamic types, there probably is a base interface that you can use instead of the concrete type